# $B\in L$ is subset of $\bigcup{L}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am unsure how to prove this.

For every $B$ in a family $L$ of sets

$$B \subset \bigcup_{A\in L}{A}$$

**It states $B$ is subset of the union of $L$.**

The definition of union of $L$ is:

$$x\in\bigcup_{A\in L}{A}  \iff \exists A(A \in L \wedge x\in A)$$

I know I have to use the definition but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be an element of $B$.  Since $B$ is an element of $L$, it follows that there is an $A\in L$ (namely, $A=B$) such that $x\in A$.  Thus, by the definition of $\bigcup_{A\in L}{A}$, it follows that $x\in \bigcup_{A\in L}{A}$.  Since this holds for every element $x$ of $B$, we have shown that
$$B\subset \bigcup_{A\in L}{A}.$$